# Save File in DocumentDb with custom name

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, azure-cosmosdb

1. I'm trying to save a XML file in DocumentDb in Json format. I have no problem in converting it and saving. All the conversion and saving are working fine.
2. However when I store my Xml file the DocumentDB provides its own file name to the file. Eg; **8756b9b9-41ac-47ca-9f4c-abec60b318be**.

But I want to save the file with my own custom name Eg; **MyXmlFile1** or **MyXmlFile2** etc;

How do I pass my custom name when saving the file? That is MyXmlFile1 or MyXmlFile2.

**"jsontoStore"** has the content of the file I want to store into DocumentDB.
Code1: Storing without passing any file name.

```
await client.CreateDocumentAsync(documentCollection.SelfLink, jsontoStore);
```

Code2: Storing with custom file name but here I'm not able to pass my content that is "jsontostore"

```
document = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(documentCollection.SelfLink,
                            new Document
                            {
                                Id = "sample1" 
                            });
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are referring to the `id` of a document, since you mentioned the auto-generated GUID.

All documents must have an unique value in the `id` property (it is the primary key for the document). If an `id` is not provided at the time of document creation, DocumentDB will generate one for you.

The solution here is to simply set the `id` field with the name of your choice (e.g. MyXmlFile1, MyXmlFile2) after you convert your XML to JSON.