# DocumentDB auto generated ID: GUID or UUID? Which variant?

Tags: guid, uuid, azure-cosmosdb

**TL;DR:** Are the IDs that are auto-generated by DocumentDB supposed to be GUIDs or UUIDs, and is there actually a difference? If they are UUIDs, then which variant/version of UUID?

**Background:** Some of the DocumentDB client libraries will auto generate an ID for you if you do not provide one. I have seen it mentioned in the [Azure blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/documentdb/2014/10/31/edit-and-query-documents-through-the-azure-portal/) and in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701877/18356) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30667987/18356) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27785611/18356) that the generated IDs are GUIDs. I know there is [some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246930/18356) over whether [GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Globally_unique_identifier#Merge_into_Universally_unique_identifier) are [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), with many people saying that they are.

**The problem:** However, I have noticed that some of the IDs that DocumentDB auto-generates do not follow the [UUID RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.3), which allows only the digits 1-5 in the "version" nibble (`V` in `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Vxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`). DocumentDB generates IDs with any hex digit in that nibble, for example [`d981befd-d19b-ee48-35bd-c1b507d3ec4f`](http://www.concurrency.com/blog/june-2015/using-existing-data-models-with-azure-documentdb-a-en), whose version nibble is the first `e` of `ee48`.

It is possible that this depends on which client is used to create the documents. In our DocumentDB database, we have documents with the third grouping `dde5`, `627a`, `fe95`, and so on. These documents were stored from within a stored procedure by calling `Collection.createDocument()` with the options `{'disableAutomaticIdGeneration': false}`. Other documents that I create through the third party [DocumentDB Studio](https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio) application always have `4xxx` in the third grouping, which is a valid UUID version. However, documents that I create through the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) have non-standard third groupings like `b359`.

**Question:** Are the auto-generated DocumentDB IDs supposed to be GUIDs or UUIDs, and is there actually a difference? If UUIDs, then which variant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Poking around in the source code on GitHub, I found that the various client and server side libraries use several different methods for creating what they're calling a GUID (in some libraries) or a UUID (in other libraries).

The [nodejs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/60e8b38a03303b0140b9d2ffdb4283ae398973c5/source/lib/base.js#L441) client, [Javascript client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js/blob/0189aef92db779ed95b60bc13f025c9be9b837ae/documentdbclient-1.4.0.js#L326), and [server-side library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/3e19ee238215a83c00097fb9c9078cbba0e0939c/utils/DocDbWrapperScript.js#L394) manufacture what they call a GUID by concatenating series of hex digits and hyphens. Note that these are random, but do not comply with the rules for creating RFC4122 version 4 UUIDs.

The [Python client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/04073053a07c6584b092968dc62fe54b2e05b875/pydocumentdb/base.py#L254) and [Java client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java/blob/ddcfa77638c948f6b9eabe204f726f2bcedd5844/src/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/DocumentClient.java#L676) call their respective standard [library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) to generate a random (version 4) UUID.

The .NET client is available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/), but the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/c2909541f02c372b4ca3cfb6ddfd5212dcb28461/sdk/Readme.md) is not yet published.

Summary:

- Microsoft is not making a distinction between GUID and UUID in their client libraries. They are using the terms interchangeably.
- What you get for a GUID/UUID depends on which client library you're using to call DocumentDB when you create your documents.